# What Does This Expression Mean?

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

I recently heard someone say "Ich hab eh..." (I'm not sure what "eh" means or how to spell it, but I tried [kind of sounds like "ay" mixed with "eh"]) "...keinen Hunger".

Does this convey a different meaning as opposed to "Ich hab keinen Hunger"?

Comment: Alternatively, you can look it up in a dictionary, e.g. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eh_sowieso_ohnedies

Comment: From the same person, you might also hear, "Das macht eh nix aus" (or "nichts aus") meaning "It doesn't matter anyway."

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as a duplicate, when one question is about etymology and the other about usage. Alex, did the answers to the other question answer yours as well?

Comment: @CarstenS Not directly; while it did enlighten me on the history of "eh" it didn't answer my original question of what it actually means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this particle is written it’s usually indeed spelled [*eh*](http://de-en.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/eh.html). It’s synonymous to longer *ohnehin* and *sowieso*, meaning ‘anyway’. In formal speech or writing, one of these should be used instead.

An English translation of the example sentence would thus be: “I’m not hungry anyway.”

PS: Also note that *keinen* often sounds like *kein*, but should still be written with the proper accusative ending.